# Cannot construct object in SELECT linq operation from a result from stored procedure in .NET

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I use Entity framework to execute a stored procedure. This procedure gives me back some result set but I cannot construct objects directly in it as it throws an error saying

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.

This is how I do it

```
return await _context.vw_Entity.FromSqlRaw("EXEC core.GetInformation @ProjectId", parameters)
  .Select(e => new DataStoreTableDetails() {
      ScdType = new LookupTableDetails() {Id = e.ScdTypeId ?? 0, Name = e.ScdTypeName}
}).ToListAsync()
```

I tried adding `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToListAsync()` but was still getting some errors. Do you have any ideas on how can I improve this and construct the object directly in the `SELECT` operation? If not possible, what is the best workaround for this scenario?

Comment: If `core.GetInformation` is not [Table Valued](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/) function. You cannot do that on the server side.

Comment: `core.GetInformation` is a procedure, so I guess I won't be able to use it. So my only hit will be to go with `AsEnumerable`? @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Yes, only in that way via `AsEnumerable()`. Only `Table Valued` functions can be embedded into SELECT Query.

Comment: I get the error `The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected.` now :/ I guess there isn't solution for this, screw it ;d

Comment: Show your proc, show your `vw_Entity`. Otherwise you are wasting time.

Comment: It's actually on the company where I work, I believe I'm not eligible to share that kind of info. Anyway, I found a non-optimal solution regarding the space. I made a class that contains ScdTypeId and ScdTypeName, constructed the general object from the call and then I filtered this object to create this LookupDetailsTable ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Check fields returned by stored proc and your Model. Or just use Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

Error suggest you to call AsEnumerable before Select, but I cannot test if it solves your problem right now.

Comment: Isn't there a way to obtain the result and construct the object without using `AsEnumerable`? I'd like the select to be done on the db side, not on the client's side

Comment: This Select will always be executed at client's side, as db execution scope ends after calling FromSqlRaw.